# How to remove extra pixels from image?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a captcha solver for a site using python, but i'm not able to remove extra pixels (those with no other pixels around it)

i've managed to get really close, removing almost every extra pixel, but my code works only once, and then it stops having any effect on the image.

```py
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract
from operator import itemgetter
import PIL.ImageOps


for x in range(im2.size[1]):
  for y in range(im2.size[0]):
    pix = im2.getpixel((y,x))
    im2.putpixel((0,21), (0,0,0))
    if pix < 180:
        try:
            left = im2.getpixel((y-1,x))
        except IndexError:
            left = 255
            pass
        try:
            right = im2.getpixel((y+1,x))
        except IndexError:
            right = 255
            pass
        try:
            up = im2.getpixel((y,x-1))
        except IndexError:
            up = 255
            pass
        try:
            down = im2.getpixel((y,x+1))
        except IndexError:
            down = 255
            pass
        if (left == 255 and right == 255) or (up == 255 and down == 255):
            im2.putpixel((y,x),(255,255,255))
```

i would like to remove any pixels with no other pixels either on the side or up and down.

[this is the image i am using to test it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjHW9.png)

[this is it before i ran the code once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzcaa.png)

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can't really *"remove"* a pixel from an image; images are raster based and rectangular so an image is W pixels wide by H pixels tall. If you *"remove"* one there will still have to be something there. So which pixels do you want to replace? And what do you want to replace them with?

Comment: I want to replace every black pixel that has no other black pixels around it with a white one

Comment: Where's your input image please? Is it pure black and white, colour or greyscale? Why have you removed your `import` statements so we can't see which libraries you are using or run your code? If you want folks to help you, it's generally a good idea to make it easy for them... ;-)

Comment: i edited and included both the image and the imports

Comment: What exactly do you mean your code only works once? And, if possible, [edit] your question and add code that shows this happening.

Comment: *"Either on the side or above or below"*? What about diagonally adjacent pixels?

Comment: i wanted to preserve as much of the letters as possible while removing everything else, so i thought removing only those would be enough

Comment: As your image doesn't touch the edges, you could just run your loops from `1` to `im2.size[1]-1` and ignore the edge pixels - then you don't need the exception handling either.

Comment: Also, you appear to be trying to do this *"in-place"*, i.e. your are using the same output image as input image. Try making a separate output image at the start with `output = np.zeros_like(ipout)` and then filling that instead.